# Wordpress post share

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress blog post sharing code like bellow. Its working in local host properly. (http://localhost/wordpress/why-should-you-take-vegen-from-very-begning/)

But when I use this code in host server it is only sharing  as like  (http:/example.com), not sharing post title. Please assist why this not working in host server.

I'm using this code.

```
 <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?><?php    
the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook.">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: Are you use this code in the same file, like as on the local server? Because if `the_permalink()` is not in the main WP Loop, it will not print nothing. And in provided cod `the_title()` function is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to share the post with title not only url. Whats your suggestions

Comment: In which file are you using this code? Did you try to use `get_the_permalink()` instead of `the_permalink()`, just in case you are not in the main loop. Another suggestion is to regenerate your permalinks in Settings - somethimes WP need this.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug